# How to animate the UIPOPoverController when tapped on info button in Maps

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview, apple-maps

I am trying to do same as of the default maps i.e present. When I click on the Annotation Pin in the Maps then I get a small popover with title and subtitle and info button, when i click on the Info button I am able launch the PopoverController straight away.

Problem :

I want to animate the popover as of the Maps, it is sliding and then the view controller is opened. how can i do that.
This is the code, I have used to launch the PopOver.

```
    detailsViewController = [[PopOverTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailsViewController];

self.poc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
[self.poc setPassthroughViews:viewsPassage];
//size as needed
poc.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 450);
//show the popover next to the annotation view (pin)
CGRect popOverFrame = view.bounds;
popOverFrame.size.width = 14;
popOverFrame.size.height = 14;
[poc presentPopoverFromRect:popOverFrame inView:view
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```